# Hide all DIV exept one called in a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So, it's a bit akward, but I found a post were somebody explained the question very good. But I can not find it sadly.
So I'll ask here, is there a possibility to hide all `div` (with ID's) on a page with JS **AND** let show one or more `div`s via link URL. Let's say like: `www.mysite.net/games?id=( _the id of the div_ )` it then should show up on the site and no one of the others.

Kinda what I want is that all `div`s are hidden and only that shows that is called by the URL `?id=[id of the div]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo. Here is the answer to my own Question:

The HTML:

```
<div hidden id="1">
  <h1>Hello Manager</h1>
  <p>What would you like to do today?</p>
  <button>View Dashboard</button>
</div>

<div hidden id="2">
  <h1>Hello employee</h1>
  <p>What would you like to do today?</p>
  <button>Clock In</button>
</div>

<div hidden id="3">
  <h1>Hello Owner</h1>
  <p>What would you like to do today?</p>
  <button>Test id</button>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
// Get query parameter
// Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/
function getQueryParameter(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  return (false);
}

// Capture the `ID` query parameter from the URL.
var id = getQueryParameter('id')
if(id.toLowerCase() === '1') {
  $('#1').show();
} else if(id.toLowerCase() === '2') {
  $('#2').show();
} else if(id.toLowerCase() === '3') {
  $('#3').show();
}
```

And here is an working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmpoKr?id=3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question right, but is this kinda what you want?

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

var id = window.location.href.split("=")[1];

divs.map(function(div) {

if(div.id !== id) { div.style['display'] = "none"; }
else { div.style['display'] = "block"; }

});
```

Comment: Not really sure about it. Cause im new in all the programming stuff could u give me an example of lets say 2 div , id 1 and id 2 how would i set them? or is that atomatic? xD im so stupid

Comment: KInda what i want is that all div are hidden and only that shows that is called by the url ?id=[id]